# How can I create an EMF model instance in Java

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have a meta model in EMF for a programming language, say X. I know that we can generate model instances conforming to the meta-model, as described here: http://eclipse.org/epsilon/doc/articles/reflective-emf-tutorial/

However, suppose I have a small program written in the language X . How can I generate an EMF model instance for this program? To be more precise, I want a function, to which, I give the program file(say HelloWorld.X) as an argument and it returns the emf model for that program. What I have done so far is that I have written a class in Java which can extract all the different types and elements from HelloWorld.X. This was possible because the meta-model of the language X had some methods like getXYZtype() and so on. However,the problem is that I am not able to understand how to generate the emf model, once I have extracted all the types and instances from the program. 
Could someone please guide me in this direction.

Looking forward to a reply,
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You have to write a parser that converts the constructs into EMF objects. For example, the [VIATRA2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIATRA) graph transformation engine did exactly do that... You have to create the EMF model graph one by one, creating the EMF model representing the language elements you have..

Comment: You could use a syntax mapper, such as [EMFText](http://www.emftext.org/index.php/EMFText). You need to define a concrete syntax for your metamodel. Then you can generate an editor that can convert text to model instances.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies. Everyone is so helpful here! I just checked EMFText. Seems like it is a solution :)